# Naming a method - suggestion

Tags: oop, naming-conventions

Imagine you have a class World. The World has to have an iterative type of functionality, semantically mimicking passing of days. Every call of a method dedicated for the implementation of this event, makes any action that is designed to happen during the day. Now the question is - how to name the method, in such a manner that calling it with a dot notation (World.method) makes linguistic and imperative sense (using possibly one word)?

Comment: Hmm... how about World.dayPassed(), or World.daysPassed(int numberOfDaysPassed)

Comment: They sound like getters for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each day is passing because the world is spinning. You are expecting a name with imperative sense, taking that in account I will suggest the following

```
World.Spin();
World.Rotate();
```

Comment: My favorite so far! I didn't go this direction. If being picky one may ask does a spin mean full spin. But I'm not picky.

Comment: You could determine the amount of spin based on the amount of time that has passed since the last update.  This could be scaled if you need to speed up or slow down time.